# How to Allow app to access device's location

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-permissions

I have created program that will access your location, for that I required permission to allow access to my location. I know the permission to be applied and how to handle that permission to but I couldn't get that done in my main Program. Every time I try to add permission It doesn't read **requestPermission()** ,to make it read I ave added  **@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)** this too.Can anyone please tell me how to add that in my code.
I have two class: **1)** NetwrokProviderActivity in which I'm calling my **2)** class,ApplocationService. Here I'm sharing my code. Please help me to resolve this

**Permission that I require**

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET
        },10);
        return;

    }
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 10:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    configureButton();
                    return;
                }
    }
}
```

**ApplocationClass in which I need to add this Permission**

```
public AppLocationService(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

            }

            if(isGPSEnabled) {

                if(location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);


                    if(locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if(location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

**NetwrokprovideActivity**

```
AppLocationService appLocationService;
Button btnNetworkProvider;
TextView txtLati;
TextView txtLongi;
TextView txtAddress;
TextView txtCity;
TextView txtState;
TextView txtCountry;
TextView txtPostalCode;
protected Context context=this;
Location location;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_network_provider);


    txtLati= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Latitude);
    txtLongi= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Longitude);
    txtAddress= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_NetAddress);
    txtCity= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_NetCity);
    txtState= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_NetState);
    txtCountry= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_NetCountry);
    txtPostalCode= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_NetPostalCode);

    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(NetworkProviderActivity.this);


    btnNetworkProvider = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Location_NetworkProvider);
    btnNetworkProvider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Location nwLocation = appLocationService
                    .getLocation();

            if (nwLocation != null) {
                double latitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();

                List<Address> addresses;
                Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

                txtLati.setText("Latitude: "+latitude);
                txtLongi.setText("Longitude: "+ longitude);

                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

                        Log.e(TAG,"network...");

                        txtAddress.setText("Address: "+address);
                        txtCity.setText("City: "+city);
                        txtState.setText("State: "+state);
                        txtCountry.setText("Country: "+country);
                        txtPostalCode.setText("Postal Code: "+postalCode);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Mobile Location (NW): \nLatitude: " + latitude
                                + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                showSettingsAlert("NETWORK");
            }

        }
    });
}


public void showSettingsAlert(String provider) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
           NetworkProviderActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle(provider + " SETTINGS");

    alertDialog
            .setMessage(provider + " is not enabled! Want to go to settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    NetworkProviderActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Its better to use `FusedLocationProviderAPI`.

Comment: It only gives latitude and longitude.

Comment: So what you need ?

Comment: I need full address.

Comment: @Piyush thanks for your suggestion.I have tried FusedLocationProvider API.But,I want my full address that is street no,local address n all.

Comment: Just convert latitude and longitude to address

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the permission on manifest, to support APIs equal and above 23 you also have to request programatically.

Comment: I have added that too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your maniufest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I have already added that in my mainfest.can you please tell me where to add permission in my code (class : ApplocationService).because I couldn't read my requestpermission() method of permission.

Comment: if (isReadStorageAllowed()) {
                   Add your google map activity 
                } else {
                    requestStoragePermission();
                }

Comment: private boolean isReadStorageAllowed() {
        //Getting the permission status
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        //If permission is granted returning true
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return true;

        //If permission is not granted returning false
        return false;
    }

Comment: //Requesting permission
    private void requestStoragePermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
                }
        /And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MAP_CODE);
    }

Comment: can you please add this code in my Given code.I couldn't get it,where to add this in my code.

Comment: Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, NonNull String[] permissions,NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if (requestCode == MAP_CODE) {
            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   You can add your map activity 
                //Displaying a toast
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @JerryTom you can add this code in that activity or frogment  from where are you calling your mapactivity

Comment: check that out.

Comment: can you please respond?

Comment: @JerryTom sorry I am not getting where are you stucking could you please explain